# jquery grab and move toggle element

Tags: jquery

i have a div that is displayed via:

```
$('a#biz-blue-lnk').click(function() {
    $('#business-blue').show();
    return false;
  });
```

what i want to figure out is when this DIV is displayed, can i enable the user to grab it and move it around the screen?  potentially if they click another DIV they could have two elements on screen... and would like them to be able to move them around to see each one...

possible?

Answer (score 1):

Look into jQueryUI & the [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)() functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), part of jQuery UI.  It's as simple as `$('#business-blue').draggable();` then!